Which target is executed first during the Linux Systemd boot process?
I have two references that both seem credible, but they offer different information.
In the first reference, it is mentioned that default.target is one of the initial targets executed. Then (assuming we want the system to boot into CLI mode) multi-user.target will be executed, followed by basic.target, and finally, we will reach sysinit.target.
However, in the second reference, the process is described in the opposite order! It states that sysinit.target is executed first, followed by basic.target, and so on.
I'm confused. Which order is correct? Which target does /sbin/init start with at the very beginning?

Check here: https://serverfault.com/questions/617398/is-there-a-way-to-see-the-execution-tree-of-systemd
In short /etc/systemd/system/default.target.

Your first reference seems to be confused, or perhaps it's describing how systemd starts figuring out the tree of dependencies between the various units.
See man 7 bootup on your system; it includes an ASCII-art chart of the systemd-based boot process.
In modern versions of systemd, the default.target is an alias for the overall goal state of the boot process, most commonly defined as either graphical.target on systems with GUI enabled, or multi-user.target if the local GUI is not needed. Once the default.target is reached and any on-going systemd operations running at that point are finished, the boot process will be essentially complete.
In practice, it is defined by /etc/systemd/system/default.target which is a symbolic link to whichever actual target is set as the default with e.g. systemctl set-default graphical.target.
On my desktop:
$ ls -l /etc/systemd/system/default.target
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 36 Mar 15  2023 /etc/systemd/system/default.target -> /lib/systemd/system/graphical.target

On a server system:
$ ls -l /etc/systemd/system/default.target
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Dec  2  2018 /etc/systemd/system/default.target -> /lib/systemd/system/multi-user.target

See man 7 bootup on any system using systemd for an ASCII art diagram of the various targets and their roles in the boot process.
So, when systemd starts at /sbin/init and there are no boot options to tell it otherwise, its "overall mission" is to reach default.target. First, it sees the default target is an alias of, say, graphical.target.
The definition of graphical.target includes the following:
Requires=multi-user.target
Wants=display-manager.service
After=multi-user.target rescue.service rescue.target display-manager.service

So, it must first satisfy multi-user.target and it would be nice to start display-manager.service too, however the latter is not absolutely essential (i.e. not worth shutting down all the regular services and falling into rescue mode if it fails).
The rescue.service and rescue.target are mentioned, but nothing has neither Required nor Wanted them, so they will be ignored by systemd this time.
The multi-user.target definition includes the following:
Requires=basic.target
After=basic.target rescue.service rescue.target

Again, it turns out basic.target must come first, and rescue.service and rescue.target are still not Required nor Wanted, so they can be ignored.
There is also a number of normal system services that are WantedBy=multi-user.target, but they all will have to wait until basic.target is satisfied first, because any service that doesn't have DefaultDependencies=no will have implicit Requires=sysinit.target and After=sysinit.target basic.target applied to them.
So, systemd will next consider basic.target. Its definition includes:
Requires=sysinit.target
Wants=sockets.target timers.target paths.target slices.target
After=sysinit.target sockets.target paths.target slices.target tmp.mount

And here we come to sysinit.target. It comes last in dependency analysis order, but it turns out it needs to be first of the target units considered so far in execution order, as all the other units considered so far have been scheduled After it. The definition of sysinit.target includes:
Wants=local-fs.target swap.target
After=local-fs.target swap.target

In practice, this causes any local filesystems to be mounted and the swap to be activated. There's also a local-fs-pre.target which can be used to start services such as software RAID, disk encryption, LVM or multipathing, which might be pre-requisites for mounting.
At this point, systemd finds a number of service units that are WantedBy=sysinit.target and have either Before=sysinit.target or no ordering requirements at all, so these can be executed immediately, in parallel. Once all units marked Before=sysinit.target have been started (or failed in the attempt), the sysinit.target can be marked as completed.
Then it will be time to start any units that are marked After=sysinit.target but Before=basic.target... and so on, until all the requirements of basic.target are satisfied, and so the target can be marked as "activated". That opens up another group of units to be started: this group includes most "normal" services, i.e. all those that don't have DefaultDependencies=no set and are WantedBy=multi-user.target.

excellent explanation, friend. thank you
